# How to process POST variables from paypal IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Currently i'm on my sanbox environment, using code from here  : https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

Evertyhing runs smooth and clear, I'm retrieving the messages on IPN history   site, I have everything saved in my log file.

The problem is here:

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];

    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
```

If I for example want to echo `$payer_email` variable nothing happens. If I want to store those variables in my database - nothing happens.

It seems that those variables are empty, and if they truly are, how can I obtain those variables and process them according to my needs.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help me, browser still shows blank page

Comment: If you're getting a blank page, you're probably getting an error. Check the PHP error log.

Comment: Is't that weird , that if I dump unchanged posted data on the beginning of the script it only shows me vector{0} ?. I really dont know what to do, it seems that paypal is not giving me any informations back